# path allowing users to view uploaded fles

Tags: php, html, file, url, hyperlink

I'm trying to add a link which allows users to view uploaded files.

Right now I have this:

```
$path = "http://" . APACHE_ROOT . UPLOAD_PATH . $result[0]['username'] . "ref_" . $ref_info[$i]['ref_email'] ."_" . $ref_info[$i]['year']; 

$status = '<a href="' . $path . '"> Uploaded </a>';
```

(Where:

```
APACHE_ROOT = /var/www/faculty-recruiting-ref/
UPLOAD_PATH = html/upload/
```

)

But I get an error that the url doesn't exist (specifically, "Google Chrome could not find var")

I also tried starting the url with "file://" but then the link does not respond.

Thanks!

PS If anyone thinks of a better title for this, please change it! I couldn't think of anything better.

EDIT: I should add that manually typing in the url does link to the correct file

Comment: Did you ever see `http://var/www/google/search-engine` ? Path is not for URL is for path

Answer (score 2):

`/var/www/faculty-recruiting-ref/` is the local path for your server, it cannot be accessed from the outside.

The APACHE_ROOT should be replaced by something like `www.yourdomain.com/faculty-recruiting-ref/`